Is there any place in the US where the Northern Cities Vowel Shift is not reversed among young speakers?
The Northern Cities Vowel Shift (NCVS) is a chain shift of vowels affecting six vowels in the Inland Northern United States during the twentieth century. This sound change progressed and spread rapidly throughout the second half of the twentieth century and into the 2000s. However, since 2015, it has been retreating quickly in many areas, especially among younger speakers. (1)(2) Studies show that speakers are partially adopting features of Low Back Merger Shift (LMBS) by lowering the DRESS vowel, which is widespread in the Western United States, and reversing the shift in the TRAP and LOT vowels. (3)
Is there any place where the young speakers are not reversing the shift in the TRAP and LOT vowels?
References:

Dinkin, A. J. (2022). Generational Phases: Toward the Low-Back Merger in Cooperstown, New York. Journal of English Linguistics, 50(3), 219-246.
Driscoll, A., & Lape, E. (2015). Reversal of the Northern Cities Shift in Syracuse, New York. University of Pennsylvania Working Papers in Linguistics, 21(2), 41-47.
Wagner, S. E., Mason, A., Nesbitt, M., Pevan, E., & Savage, M. (2016). Reversal and re-organization of the Northern Cities Shift in Michigan. University of Pennsylvania Working Papers in Linguistics, 22(2), 19.

